# How do you use Javascript to duplicate form fields?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

For instance, I want to have a html form that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Field A:</td>
     <td><input type='text' name='fielda[1]'></td>
     <td>Field B:</td>
     <td><textarea name='fieldb[1]'></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to add a button that duplicates my entire above form, but changes the 1 to a 2 for all of the fields. Not just one field, but the entire section of code, including the table.There will be more/different fields than the ones I posted as well.

I've already tried this solution, which does exactly what I need:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

But for some reason, could not duplicate the functionality when copying the code examples to test. I even tried literally copying the entire page source to get it to work, with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
          $countForms = 1;
          $.fn.addForms = function(){
                var myform = "<table>"+
                 "  <tr>"+
                 "     <td>Field A ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                 "     <td><input type='text' name='fielda["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
                 "     <td>Field B ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                 "     <td><textarea name='fieldb["+$countForms+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                 "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                 "  </tr>"+
                 "</table>";

                 myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
                 $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

                 $(this).append(myform);
                 $countForms++;
          };
    })(jQuery);     

    $(function(){
        $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
            $("#container").addForms();
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybutton">add form</button>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Very simple. But wouldn't this require some includes for jquery? (i'm sorry, I really don't know much about jquery) What else is needed to complete the code?

Comment: Yes, but you could do it pretty much as easily using innerHTML from plain JavaScript if you wanted to.

Comment: include jquery on the page, you can put this code in a separate file as a list of plugins. wait a minute, and I complete with an example

Comment: Do I just put this on a <input onclick button? What about removing the added form section?

Comment: How do you remove one of these created areas?

Comment: Andres, if you don't mind my asking, why do you have your initial function as "function(jQuery)" or "function($)"?  I'm really new to jQuery, so I don't understand why you would pass jQuery as an argument.  What does that even mean?  Is that how you manage to get access to its library?

Comment: @user919860 all right, first looking to have a reference to the object for faster access, second if you use other libraries we have in our context, the variable "$" without replacing them in other like Mootools.
Normally all plugins are made with a structure "closure" to maintain the privacy of the variables.

Answer (score 6):

There's a technique called **supplant** that does this.  I didn't write it, I think Douglas Crockford did.  But I'll quote it:

Now that your JavaScript program has received the data, what can it do with it? One of the simplest things is client-side HTML generation.

```
var template = '<table border="{border}"><tr><th>Last</th><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
   '<tr><th>First</th><td>{first}</td></tr></table>';
```

Notice that we have an HTML template with three variables in it. Then we'll obtain a JSON object containing members that match the variables.

```
var data = { 
    "first": "Carl", 
    "last": "Hollywood",    
    "border": 2 
};
```

We can then use a supplant method to fill in the template with the data.

```
mydiv.innerHTML = template.supplant(data);
```

JavaScript strings do not come with a supplant method, but that is ok because JavaScript allows us to augment the built-in types, giving them the features we need.

```
String.prototype.supplant = function (o) { 
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g, 
        function (a, b) {  
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? 
                r : a; 
        }
    ); 
};
```

From http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

One technique I've seen to avoid that messy variable assignment of a template is to do:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/html">
  <tr>
     <td>Field A:</td>
     <td><input type='text' name='fielda[{id}]'></td>
     <td>Field B:</td>
     <td><textarea name='fieldb[{id}]'></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

This will let your write much prettier code as you can reference it with getElementById.

So in your case, rather than populating it with a JSON object, you would just look over however many rows you need to add and replace the id's.

Answer (score 4):

The example you are linking to, has a hidden version of the form that is used as a template. This template has an ID (`readroot`), that allows it to be easily selected (`getElementById`), then cloned (`node.cloneNode()`) and injected into the DOM above (`node.insertBefore()`) a second marker in the source (`writeroot`).

The number of duplications is kept accounted for in the variable `counter`. Its' contents are updated (incremented) on every cloning, and its' value is then appended to all the field names in the cloned node. (The original template-nodes' fields have no numeric suffix.)

It's all really very simple, just study the javascript in the head-portion of the webpage. Google the parts you can't understand, and you will achieve what you're looking for, and will learn some in the process. Profit!

Comment: I totally understand what the code is trying to do, but I can't isolate where the bug is when I literally copypasta the code.

Comment: @Ryan: can you paste your complete source into a pastebin somewhere? Psychic debugging is too hard this time of day. (CET+1)

Comment: I tried first copying the code and editing it to do what I needed. When that didn't work (clicking the button did nothing), I tried copying the exact source for the entire page, and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, read you question incorrectly. This is better:

```
function duplicate(frm) {
  newfrm = $(frm).clone();
  $(newfrm).each(function(i,o) {
     if (o.name != null) { // or if ($(o).attr("name"))
       o.name = replaceIndex(o.name);
     }
  });
  $(frm).parent().append(newfrm);
}
```

Not sure about actual syntax. E.g. how do you test for attribute presence. Easy to find in google, though.
Here replaceIndex(string) uses lastIndexOf() to find last [x] and replace it to [x+1].

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some kind of library like jQuery, as some have suggested. It'll pay off.

Regarding making a template and cloning it in javascript, there are some problems when using IE (all versions as far as I know). IE will disregard any programmatical changes to 'name' property when duplicating e.g. radio buttons in a form. So unless you create custom event handlers for the radio buttons, they will not work as expected when you copy them across sections (e.g. checking a button in one section will cause a button in another section to be unchecked).