# How to limit Javascript from duplicate form fields?

Tags: php, javascript

i found nice javascript here [javascript duplicate field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462119/how-do-you-use-javascript-to-duplicate-form-fields)

but the problem is i want limit function can duplicate only until 10 rows.

here my code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
          $countForms = 1;
          $.fn.addForms = function(){
                        var myform = "<table>"+
                         "  <tr>"+
                         "     <td>Field A ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                         "     <td><input type='text' name='fielda["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
                         "     <td>Field B ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                         "     <td><textarea name='fieldb["+$countForms+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                         "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                         "  </tr>"+
                         "</table>";

                         myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
                         $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

                         $(this).append(myform);
                         $countForms++;
          };
    })(jQuery);         

    $(function(){
        $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
                $("#container").addForms();
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybutton">add form</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

so any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: you could set some max Duplication value like maxDuplicateCount = 10, and then check against it while calling addForms() .. wont that help..?

Comment: sorry, i'm really newbie..can you show where should i put that code?

Comment: see answer by @mrtsherman posted below, thats wat i meant

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I feel dirty for suggesting this. You had so many other, better answers in your linked question.

```
  $.fn.addForms = function(){
      if ($countForms == 10 ) {
          $("#mybutton").unbind("click");
          return;
      }
      var myform = "<table>"+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check into the function forcing it to stop at 10 fields

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($){
    $countForms = 1;
    $formLimit = 10;
    $.fn.addForms = function(){
      if(countForms >= formLimt){
        return;
      }
      var myform =  "<table>"+
                    "  <tr>"+
                    "    <td>Field A ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                    "    <td><input type='text' name='fielda["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
                    "    <td>Field B ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                    "    <td><textarea name='fieldb["+$countForms+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                    "    <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                    "  </tr>"+
                    "</table>";

      myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
      $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

      $(this).append(myform);
      $countForms++;
    };
  })(jQuery);         

  $(function(){
    $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
      $("#container").addForms();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
```